# How can you push a new view with a grouped table?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

Ive been trying to push a new view when a cell is tapped but absolutely nothing happens. I figured grouped style pushed the same as plain. Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
contactArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPod",@"MacBook",@"MacBook     Pro",nil];
shareArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Flex",@"AIR",@"PhotoShop",@"Flash",nil];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if(section == 0)
    return [contactArray count];
else
    return [shareArray count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if(section == 0){
    return @"Contact";
}else{
    return @"Share";
}
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if(section == 0){
    return @"Footer for Apple Products";
}else{
    return @"Footer for Adobe Softwares";
}
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...
if(indexPath.section == 0){
    cell.text = [contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else{
    cell.text = [shareArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
if([contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"iPhone"){
    LandscapeHydrogen *abo = [[LandscapeHydrogen alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandscapeHydrogen" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:abo animated:NO];
[abo release];
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
else if (indexPath.section == 1 & indexPath.row == 0){
        FaceBook *nextController = [[FaceBook alloc] initWithNibName:@"FaceBook" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put a breakpoint at the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to see if the if statement is true.

Try changing

```
if([contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"iPhone"){
```

to

```
if([[contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]){
```

Comment: Still Nothing, Debugger says mach msg trap

Comment: Where did you set the breakpoint? Set it at the if statement and step over each line to see how the code executes.

Comment: I set it right on the if statement inside didselectrowatindexpath method. Nothing was displayed in the debugger but the red arrow did go through the entire method like it would normally. If you know any other way to make a grouped table push any view, that would work. I just need it to push a few different views depending on whats selected.

Comment: Solved with
 else if (indexPath.section == 1 & indexPath.row == 0){
  FaceBook *nextController = [[FaceBook alloc] initWithNibName:@"FaceBook" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

```
  YourNextViewController  *   nextViewController = [[YourNextViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"YourNextViewController" bundle: nil];  

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        nextViewController.title = [_contactArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
        break;

    case 1:
        nextViewController.title = [_shareArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```